# Opening a fancybox from fullcalendar event - clicking the event opens the previouosly selected event's url

Tags: php, jquery, fancybox, fullcalendar

First time question asker here. I used several different threads on here to construct a fullcalendar that opens event information in a fancybox.  More specifically, each day has an link (structured as an event) that opens a list of that days events in a fancybox.

I constructed the calendar and fancybox links with the following code:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  height: 550,
  eventClick: function(event) {
    if (event.url) {
      $("a").fancybox({
        'href'  : event.url,
        'width' : '6',
        'height'        : '100%',
        'transitionIn'  : 'elastic',
        'transitionOut' : 'elastic',
        'type'          : 'iframe'
      });
      return false;
    }
  },

  eventSources: [
    {
      events: [
      <?php
      $query = "SELECT date, COUNT(*) AS num_events FROM events GROUP BY date ORDER BY date";
      $result = mysql_query($query);
      $numRows = mysql_num_rows($result);
      $count = 0;
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
      {
        $count++;
        $num_events = $row['num_events'];
        if ($num_events == '1') {$num_events .= ' event';}
        else {$num_events .= ' events';}
        $url = 'dayEvents.php?d='.$row['date'];
        $date = $row['date'];
        ?>
        {
        title   : '<?php echo $num_events; ?>',
        start   : '<?php echo $date; ?>',
        url : '<?php echo $url; ?> '
        }<?php if ($count < $numRows) { echo ","; } ?>
      <?php }?>                             
      ],
      color: 'white',
      textColor: '#2287c4'
    }
  ]
})

});
```

Here is the scenario I'm experiencing:

I click on link A, and nothing happens.
I click on link A again, and the fancybox opens with link A's url. I exit the fancybox. 
I click on link B, and the fancybox opens with link A's url again. I exit the fancybox.
I click on link C, and the fancybox opens with link B's url.
Additionally, if I click on any link outside of the calendar, it opens a fancybox with link C's url (this doesn't happen until I've clicked on an event in the calendar).

Essentially, the links are delaying by one click, and the fancybox is creating an event handler for any link on the page.  Does anyone have an idea what could be causing this and what I can do to fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently each time your user clicks on an event, your code is placing a fancy box on every 'a' element on the whole page causing the strange behavior you see.

Instead of using the 'eventClick' callback, put your fancybox init code in the 'eventAfterRender' callback.  As its name implies, this callback is called after each calendar event is drawn.  This way, the fancy boxes will be initialized when the calendar loads and will be ready to go when the user clicks an event.

Also, you need to modify your jquery selector from $("a").fancybox(....  to $("a",element).fancybox(... where 'element' is a parameter supplied to the eventAfterRender callback by fullcalendar (see the fullcalendar docs on the eventAfterRender function).  This will restrict the selector to the div for the single calendar event that was just rendered.

**EDIT**
After reading more about fancybox, I see that you can open it directly without first attaching it to an <a> element.  This is probably a much better solution than what I suggested above since you won't be initializing any fancyboxes unless the user actually clicks on a calendar event.  So in your fullcalendar initialization, just replace your eventClick with the following:

```
eventClick: function(event) {
    if (event.url) {
      $.fancybox({
        'href' : event.url,
        'type' : 'iframe',
         other options as you like...
      });
      return false;
    }
  },
```